# Extracting integral solutions from a quartic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation
\begin{equation*}
y^{4} + 4y^{3} + 10y^{2} + 12y - 27 = 0
\end{equation*}
has two integral roots. Without resorting to the quartic formula, how would one extract the roots from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem): in your case, it tells us that any integer root must divide $-27$. Therefore, it has to be one of these numbers: $\pm1$, $\pm3$, $\pm9$, or $\pm27$.

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest method to extract an integral root.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use an integer [polynomial factorisation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials) , which gives the factorization
$$
(y^2 + 2y + 9)(y + 3)(y - 1).
$$
Of course, the rational root test is much better suited here (and is performed before anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try $$y=3$$ or $$y=1$$ both are divisors of $$27$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way we might proceed:

There is an old and simple result:

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring and let

$p(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n p_i x^i \in R[x]; \tag 1$

then $1$ is a root of $p(x)$ if and only if the sum of the coefficients of $p(x)$ is $0$; that is,

$p(1) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \displaystyle \sum_0^n p_i = 0; \tag 2$

this is an immediate consequence of

$p(1) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n p_i 1^i = \sum_0^n p_i, \tag 3$

as is easy to see.

We can apply this observation to

$q(y) = y^4 + 4y^3 + 10y^2 + 12y - 27, \tag 4$

and immediately conclude $1$ is a zero of $q(y)$.  Next we synthetically divide $q(y)$ by $y - 1$, and obtain

$q(y) = y^4 + 4y^3 + 10y^2 + 12y - 27 = (y - 1)(y^3 + 5y^2 + 15y + 27); \tag 5$

***We Check:***

$(y - 1)(y^3 + 5y^2 + 15y + 27) = y^4 + 5y^3 + 15y^2 + 27y -  y^3 - 5y^2 - 15y - 27$
$= y^4+ 4y^3 + 10y^2 + 12y - 27 = q(y); \tag 6$

setting

$s(y) = y^3 + 5y^2 + 15y + 27, \tag 7$

we now invoke the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to limit the integer candidates for a zero of this cubic polynomial to the (integer) divisors of the constant term, that is, to $\pm 1$, $\pm 3$, $\pm 9$, and $\pm 27$; we then make a (hopefully) intelligent guess that

$s(-3) = 0 \tag 8$

might hold; and indeed we see that

$s(-3) = -27 + 45 - 45 + 27 = 0; \tag 9$

thus $-3$ is also a root of $q(y)$; now we (again, synthetically) divide $s(y)$ by $y + 3$:

$s(y) = y^3 + 5y^2 + 15y + 27 = (y + 3)(y^2 + 2y + 9), \tag{10}$

and again we may check:

$(y + 3)(y^2 + 2y + 9) = y^3 + 2y^2 + 9y + 3y^2 + 6y + 27$
$= y^3 + 5y^2 + 15y + 27 = s(y); \tag{11}$

it follows that

$q(y) = (y - 1)(y + 3)(y^2 + 2y + 9); \tag{12}$

we have now extracted two integral roots of $q(y)$; the remaining zeroes satisfy the quadratic equation

$y^2 + 2y + 9 = 0; \tag{13}$

the "formula" yields

$y = \dfrac{-2 \pm \sqrt{-32}}{2} = \dfrac{-2 \pm 4 \sqrt{-2}}{2} = -1 \pm 2i\sqrt 2; \tag{14}$

we see the remaining two roots of $q(y)$ form a complex conjugate pair, ***not integers!***  We have thus verified that $q(y)$ has precisely two integral zeroes, $1$ and $-3$.

Comment: The Rational Root Test is the (convenient) method to extract the root from the given polynomial ... but this is cute.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire:  well, shucks, glad you thought it was pretty!

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire:  I edited in a few words on the RRT; cf. ca. (7)-(8).  Cheers!