# What are the conditions for a quartic equation to have positive integer roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

What are the conditions for a quartic equation to have positive integer roots?
$$Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E = 0$$

Comment: I don't think there's a general set of conditions for the roots to be positive integers.

Answer (score 2):

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), we need that an integral
root  is a divisor of $E$. This is not a sufficient condition, but we have only to consider the divisors of $E$ and test them.

For an example see here: [Extracting integral solutions from a quartic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233358/extracting-integral-solutions-from-a-quartic-equation/3233364)